# SQL Group Results and Add them up based on product

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got the following SQL which basically works out the costings etc for each item.

```
SELECT
    L.LocID,
    L.LocationName,
    L.LocationSqrMtr,
    L.LocationAddress,
    L.LocationPostCode,
    L.LocationContact,
    I.SubPIDItemID,
    I.SPID,
    I.ProductID,
    C.SubPIDCostID,
    C.PricePerItem,
    C.ManDayPerItem
FROM
    dbo.SubPIDCosts AS C
    INNER JOIN dbo.SubPIDItems AS I ON
        C.ProductID = I.ProductID
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.SubPIDLocations AS L ON
        I.LocationID = L.LocID AND C.LocationID = L.LocID
WHERE C.SPID = 48
```

This returns:

```
+-------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+---------------+-----+----+---+-----+--------+--------+--------+------+
| LocID | LocationName | LocationSqrMtr | LocationAddress | LocationPostCode | LocationContact | SubPIDItemID |   SPID   | ProductID | SubPIDCostID | PricePerItem | ManDayPerItem |     |    |   |     |        |        |        |      |
+-------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+---------------+-----+----+---+-----+--------+--------+--------+------+
| 379   |              |                | Location        | 1                | 1               | 345          | Generic  | Building  | Generic      | Building     | NULL          | 158 | 48 |   |     |        | 108    | 0.3400 | 6.17 |
| 379   |              |                | Location        | 1                | 1               | 345          | Generic  | Building  | Generic      | Building     | NULL          | 159 | 48 | 1 | 109 | 0.3400 |        | .47    |      |
| 379   | 3            | Location       | 1               | 615              | Generic         | Building     | Generic  | Building  | NULL         | 160          | 48            |     |    |   | 110 | 0.7317 | 0.50   |        |      |
| 379   | 4            | Location       |                 |                  | 615             | Generic      | Building | Generic   | Building     | NULL         | 161           | 48  |    |   |     | 111    | 0.7317 | 0.50   |      |
| 379   | 4            | Location       |                 |                  | 615             | Generic      | Building | Generic   | Building     | NULL         | 16            |     | 48 | 1 | 11  |        | 0.7317 | 0.50   |      |
+-------+--------------+----------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+--------------+--------------+---------------+-----+----+---+-----+--------+--------+--------+------+
```

[image]

But what I would like to do is group it by the product ID. So all the ones that are ProductID 22 it should add the values up for ManDayPerItem and PricePerItem and LocationSqrMtr

It's used in the following context

[image]

I'd like to have them grouped nicely in that list.

Comment: You already have the answer, you just don't realize it yet (it's in the sentence that starts with "but what I would like"). Look up `GROUP BY`.

Comment: The thing is, you have to get rid of superflous columns (e.g. location ID) unless you want to have separate rows for your separate location/product combinations.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, group by:

```
SELECT ProductID, SUM(ManDayPerItem), SUM(PricePerItem), SUM(LocationSqrMtr)
FROM
    dbo.SubPIDCosts AS C
    INNER JOIN dbo.SubPIDItems AS I ON
        C.ProductID = I.ProductID
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.SubPIDLocations AS L ON
        I.LocationID = L.LocID AND C.LocationID = L.LocID
WHERE C.SPID = 48
GROUP BY ProductID;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for that, I get a Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator. error though.

Comment: @TomBeech you will need to convert the columns to numeric types first (for example `CAST(PricePerItem AS money)`). To begin with, you have `PricePerItem='Building'` in your data. This seems semantically incorrect to me.

Comment: I can't quite get the format for the cast right, SUM(Cast(ManDayPerItem as Decimal) doesn't seem to work

Comment: @TomBeech . . . use the `str()` function to format the number.